# Angular.js 2: Access component of a directive

Tags: javascript, angular

Consider the following snippet of `Parent`'s template:

```
<div *ngFor= "let event of events" >
     <event-thumbnail [theEvent] = 'event'></event-thumbnail>                    
</div>
```

Also `event-thumbnail` component definition is:

```
export class EventThumbnailComponent{
  intoroduceYourself(){
      console.log('I am X');
  }
}
```

In `Parent` component class, I want to iterate over all generated `event-thumbnail` elements, access the component beneath each, and call `introduceYourself` function on single one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Child listens for parent event in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677122/child-listens-for-parent-event-in-angular-2)? i.e. allow your `EventThumbnailComponent` to listen to the parents event, that way you don't have to iterate the dom elements manually.

Comment: In particular, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40143881/6680611) in the duplicate target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `@ViewChildren()` decorator to get a list of all instances of a specific component type within the view:

```
class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChildren(EventThumbnailComponent)
    eventThumbnails: QueryList<EventThumbnailComponent>;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // Loop over your components and call the method on each one
        this.eventThumbnails.forEach(component => component.introduceYourself());

        // You can also subscribe to changes...
        this.eventThumbnails.changes.subscribe(r => {             
            // Do something when the QueryList changes
        });
    }
}
```

The `eventThumbnails` property will be updated whenever an instance of this component is added to or removed from the view. Notice the `eventThumbnails` is not set until `ngAfterViewInit`.

See the docs here for more information:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Perfect answer. So nothing against you, @DRiFTy, but isn't it sad that we have regressed to a level of dom manipulation abstraction far below that offered by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your child component should have `@Input() theEvent` to get access to the event you are passing. Then you can use the following lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit(){
   introduceYourself(){
      console.log('I am X');
   }
}
```