# Update input value in child even when it stays unchanged in parent angular 2+

Tags: angular

I am passing a value to a child component like so ..

```html
<app-child-component[prop1]='prop1'></app-child-component>
```

and catching it in the child like so ..

```js
 @Input() prop1:boolean;
```

This is a boolean value that changes from false to true in the parent when a button is pressed. In the child it is changed back to false when another button is clicked.

At this point if I press the button in parent again nothing happens. The value of prop1 is still true in the parent so no change is detected and nothing is sent to the child. I understand this is expected behavior.

Is there a way however to still force the value of prop1 to be pushed to the child again?

EDIT: I might need two-way data binding in this scenario but as I am not actually using the value of prop1 in the parent just the ability to update it again in the child should suffice.

Comment: you need to use two way binding in angular to do that, have a look at https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html

Comment: @ArunGopinathan Please see the edit note. 2-way data binding might be the way to go but I don't really need it in this scenario if there is another way to achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37677652/1009922). You could use a `Subject` to notify the child that the button of the parent component was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay found a way without 2-way data binding..

In the parent ..

```html
<button type="button" (click)="prop1=!prop1">...</button>
<app-child-component [setProp]='prop1'></app-child-component>
```

And in the child ..

```js
prop1:boolean;
  @Input()
  set setProp(p: boolean) {
    this.prop1 = true;
}
```

So every time I click the button in the parent the value changes and is sent to the child every time. And since a button click in the parent always means the value needs to be true in the child, that is what i am doing in the set function.

Edit: The use case for this is a modal dialog with the modal being in a child component. Parent has the button to open the modal and the modal has a close button.

Comment: Does that answer the question? You indicate in the title that the value in the parent does not change.

Comment: I might need to reword my question. I am trying to send a button click from the parent. The value in the parent does not really matter

Comment: You may want to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37677122/1009922), which deals exactly with this subject.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to emit the value from the chld to the parent, so yea 2 way binding

in child

```
  @Output() booleanEmitter= new EventEmitter();

onButtonClick(){
    this.booleanEmitter.emit(this.prop1);
}
```

in parent

```
<app-child-component (booleanEmitter)="getProp($event)"  [prop1]='prop1'></app-child-component>

getProp($event){
this.prop = $event as boolean
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the 2 way data binding example. I am going to use this if I can't find another way. It feels wrong though to use 2 way data binding when I am not really using the data in the parent.

Comment: then you can use a service